# "(0 was unexpected at this time" when calling function with FOR loop

Tags: batch-file

I have a quite long program written up. It's well over 4000 lines, nearing 5000 and I need some help. The only FOR loop in the entire program does not work. I have searched and searched and finally, I came to the conclusion that the only way I could get an answer was by asking.

In the script, I have a function called D. It loops through 32 characters in a string that is selected on call and calls another function, C, to color the output. It scrolls through and looks at the string and individually looks at each character before printing the result on screen. When it reaches the last character it returns to the main script. It is called as follows:

```
CALL :D 15
```

This would select the string M015 (it's a long story) to be read out. The actual function is written as follows:

```
:D
FOR /L %%G (0,1,31) DO (
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="0" CALL :C 08 "n"
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="1" CALL :C 2A "G"
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="2" CALL :C 87 "S"
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="3" CALL :C 6E "W"
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="4" CALL :C %BG%A "T"
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="5" CALL :C %BG%A "n"
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="6" CALL :C 6E "H"
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="7" CALL :C 91 "m"
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="8" CALL :C 19 "m"
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="9" CALL :C B3 "M"
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="A" CALL :C 4C "m"
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="B" CALL :C C4 "M"
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="C" CALL :C 6E "O"
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="D" CALL :C 6E "W"
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="E" CALL :C 2A "W"
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="F" CALL :C %BG%D "X"
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="G" CALL :C 6E "E"
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="H" CALL :C 48 "E"
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="I" CALL :C 68 "n"
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="J" CALL :C E6 "m"
    IF "!M%MAP%%1:~%%G,1!"=="K" CALL :C E6 "W"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Where %%G is the counter for the FOR loop, %MAP% is an external variable that selects a matrix, %1 is the argument used to select the individual array of that matrix, and %BG% is the background color of the terminal. All of these are assigned prior to execution by a long shot (think 2000-3000 lines ahead of time).

However, when I run the function MAP2 (Which calls this function 16 times to display the entire array), it will begin to print the first line (display the array number) and then crash. By quick screenshotting and pasting into Paint, I see the error is "(0 was unexpected at this time."
This makes no sense to me... The only (0 I can find is at the beginning of the range statement, and that's all correct to my knowledge.

Is there something else I'm doing wrong to make this happen?

Comment: "the only way I could get an answer was by asking" - that's the generally accepted method, yes :-) The *first* thing you should do is put an `@echo on` at the top of that code so you can see what it's doing.

Comment: I've tried this already. It's getting to the FOR loop and stopping.

Comment: You troubleshoot batch files by executing them from the cmd prompt with echo on. That way you do not need to do any quick screen captures.

Comment: Again - I have done this already. It gets to the FOR statement and stops.

Answer (score 2):

> The only `(0` I can find is at the beginning of the range statement, and that's all correct to my knowledge.

To which I would respond:

- If that's the only place where there's a `(0`, that's probably where you should be looking; and
- The phrase "to my knowledge" depends greatly upon your actual level of knowledge :-)

Your `(0 was unexpected at this time` is caused by the fact that you have the syntax wrong.

The "loop over number range" syntax is (note the presence of `IN`):

```
FOR /L %%G IN (0,1,31) DO (
```

If you change it to that, you'll get rid of the *immediate* problem - I'm not vouching for the sanity or otherwise of the rest of your multi-thousand line batch file, you may have to ask *other* questions for that :-)

Comment: I can't believe I forgot to add "IN"... The program is still not working. It gets to the line and says "The syntax of the command is incorrect" now.